# Testing for convergence $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{j}p_i}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

How would we test for convergence the series below?

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{j}p_i}$$
where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number. I'd be glad to learn an elementary way. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $p_j \geq j$.

Comment: the sum is convergent in think :D , by prime number theorem

Comment: @JoseGarcia Can we consider that elementary?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: then the question turns into a beautiful series to compute by comparison test! Got it! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Where do you get all these crazy questions?  (Every time I see a question by "Chris's sister and pals", I think to myself "This is going to be an interesting/hard question...")

Comment: @anorton: honestly, it's the last question that came to my mind today and I was very curious to find an answer. Actually, I was aware of the prime number theorem, but I felt that there must be some elementary way around.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I'd like to choose your answer if you give me this possibility. :-)

Comment: @anorton Although I think your comment is fun, I say we do not advance in the reflection unless we encounter hard questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by priem number theorem $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j} \sim \frac{n^{2}ln(n)}{2} $$

so your series goes about $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^{2}ln(n)} $$

which is itself convergent..